# Python code to convert value from file into array

Tags: python

I'm having some issues with Python. I'm creating a Python code that can go search and collect values from a file and put them in an array so I can manipulate later on: that includes writing to a file, plotting or do some computation with. The files are as follows:

```
file 1 (text file)
  a = 1.2
  a = 2.2
  a = 6.5

file 2 (text file)
  b = 1.0 E-5
  b = 2.5 E-4
```

where the array would be

```
  a_array = [1.2, 2.2, 6.5]
  b_array = [1.0e-5, 2.5e-4]
```

I want to create an array for values of `a` and an array for values of `b`. I wrote this following code for file_1

```
a_array = []
for line in open (file_1):  # it's a text file, was having issue with the format on this site
    if line.startswith("a ="):
    a = line[3:]  # this to print from the 3rd value 
    print a
    a_array.append(a)      
    print a_array
```

It prints out the following:

```
 ['1.2']
 ['1.2', '2.2']
 ['1.2', '2.2', '6.5']
```

The third line is exactly what I want but not the other two lines.

Comment: That's because you have the `print` command inside the loop. Also notice that you have a `list`, not a `numpy.array` and that you have datatype `str`, not `float`, so even the last line is not _exactly_ what you want.

Comment: I feel like you need to learn some programming basics. Leave this project for now and create something much simpler first.

Comment: indentation was the issue :P took me a while to notice it after your comment. Thanks a lot yall. Programming is a continuous learning trip; I'm new at python.

Answer (score 0):

Michael is correct in the comments, you have the `print` command inside the `for` loop, so it *displays* each loop, but at the end, `a_arra`y will be only the final displayed value.

The more interesting question is how to get from your third line (`['1.2', '2.2', '6.5']`, a list of strings) to what you want (`a_array = [1.2, 2.2, 6.5]`, a list of numbers).

If you know they are all numbers, you can use `a_array.append(float(a))`, but that runs into an issue with `b`, using scientific notation. Fortunately, Python can transcribe scientific notation like `b` but without spaces. To do so, you would use `replace` to remove all spaces before converting. It doesn't matter if there aren't spaces, so this method works for `a` as well (written in Python 3.5.2):

```
a_array = []
b_array = []
for line in open (file_1): # didn't correct formatting for opening text file
    if line.startswith("a="):          
        a=line[3:]  #this to print from the 3rd value 
        a_array.append(float(a.replace(' ','')))    
    elif line.startswith("b="):
        b=line[3:]
        b_array.append(float(b.replace(' ','')))
```

Comment: thank you for the assistance. It took me a while to notice the indentation was my issue. Thank you :)